# Python docx - Multiple color in one line

Tags: python, colors, fonts, python-docx

I'm currently genereting a word file using python docx library.

I create multiple table contening text and variables.
When there is a variable in the line I mark them like this : <Variable_name>var

I need to change the color of the delimiter <>var to red to highlight it.

The only way think i've found about text color is:

```
p=document.add_paragraph()
wp = p.add_run('I want this sentence colored red with fontsize=22')
wp.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255,0,0)
```

But it's for the all paragraph, not a specific part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character-level formatting ("font" characteristics) is controlled at the run level. A run is a sequence of characters that share the same character-level formatting. Consequently, if you want a "run" of red characters inside a normally formatted paragraph, you need three runs; one before, one red, and one after.

```
paragraph = document.add_paragraph()
paragraph.add_run("The part before the red bit ")
run = paragraph.add_run("the red bit")
run.font ... # --- make the font of this run red ---
paragraph.add_run(" the part after the red bit.")
```

Comment: You are a life saver. Not only that you found me a answer. But you also help me understand how docx paragraph works. Before that, if i need multiple element to go in the same paragraph, i was creating a string that was containing every element. And then add a paragraph with this string. So i was enable to modify some part of my paragraph (like style or alignement)